# by pass some line with sprin batch regarding to a condition

Tags: java, algorithm, spring-batch

Excuse me but this may be a noob question for some but it just crossed my mind and I think it is worth to fix my ideas and get a relevant recommandation from some experts. thank you

I'm using spring batch to read records line and transform then to new models.

All my file lines have this format:

```
propertie1 ; prop2 ; prop3 ; prop4 ; prop5
```

the process is like this : i read this line and pass it to the processor to do somme stuff

My problem is that, i should pass to the item processor only lines with this condition:

```
If for the same value of property 5 there are 2 or more lines
- a line with prop 4 = 0 
- a line with prop 4 = 1 
and all values are identical (prop1, prop2, prop3 , ...)
send to the processor only the line which prp 4 = 1
```

So as first solution, i 'l thinking to use a Map to store all lines that verified this condition and then from that Map i pass all record to the processor:

algo:

1. read line by line the file
2. store the line on Map Structure like this: [prop5, line]
3. if the new line have the same prop 5 (key exist on map), and have the sames values the i pass to test the prop 4 and store only the line with value equal to 1.
4. in the final , i have a map with all line that verfiy the condition.
5. from that Map , do iteration and pass every record to the processor to continue the transformation

So, is my algo is correct , its the best any idea can help me find other solution best sofisticated and smart ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i like to share my strategie to see if there is anotehr way  to do or if there is

Comment: It's too broad.

Comment: If the Map fits in your memory, this sounds ok.

Comment: thank you for your cooperation, so do you thing this is the best appraoch ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok to me, but you shall use chunks in your step to avoid an out of memory Exception.

[Chunk reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html)